# Is there a more efficient algorithm for this process?

Tags: python, algorithm, conditional-statements

I have a simple algorithm, which loops the variable self.h between 1 and 359. Here it is:

```
while True:
    if self.h <= 1:
        self.up = True
    elif self.h >= 359:
        self.up = False

    if self.up:
        self.h += 1
    else:
        self.h -= 1
```

Sorry if this is a vague question, but is there a better way of doing this, perhaps without the added conditional of checking self.h? It feels quite clumsy.

Thanks

Comment: you are looking for a more efficient way to perform an **infinite cycle**? Good luck with that!

Comment: Am I right: if self.h = 360, then you'll set self.up to False and decrease self.h by 1 to 359.  Then self.up remains False.  self.h decreases, and this continues until self.h=1.  Then self.up becomes True.  Then it increases until it's 359, then decreases, then increases...    It's not at all clear to me what the behavior should be if the loop begins with self.h = 100, say.

Comment: I should clarify that I have set self.h to start at 1, you're right if it didn't there would be no loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the entire thing like this

```
while True:
    if self.h <= 1:
        incr = 1
    elif self.h >= 359:
        incr = -1
    self.h += incr
    ...
    ...
```

It will keep on adding `1` until `self.h` is lesser than 359 otherwise it will add `-1`.

Comment: I think this will give a sequence 1, 2, ..., 359, 358, 359, 358 ...

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov You are right. Fixed it now :-)

Comment: This is nicely compact, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import cycle, chain
x = cycle(chain(range(1, 359), range(359, 1, -1)))
```

then just

```
self.h = next(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code more readable You may write your own range function, for example:

```
def myrange(fr, to):
    while True:
        for i in xrange(fr, to):
            yield i
        for i in xrange(to, fr, -1):
            yield i

for m in myrange(1, 359):
    print m
```